# How to setup Magento 1.x (or 2.0) run with Oracle Database (instead of MySql)

Tags: database

As title, i want to setup Magento 1.x (or 2.0) run with Oracle Database (instead of MySql). It possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magento does not support anything else other than MySQL.Magento Enterprise Edition 1.11 or greater and ask Magento for the Oracle resource helpers.

follow [blog](http://www.dckap.com/blog/how-to-integrate-magento-with-oracle-erp/) maybe helpful.

Comment: Is mssql adapters available in Magento EE support.can i use magento with mssql ?

Comment: http://www.magentocommerce.com/images/uploads/RDBMS_Guide2.pdf read this maybe helpful

Comment: @QaisarSatti i read this document but can't find out solution!

Comment: now, Oracle adapter haven't include in Magento ^^